# Greasemonkey script to select a dropdown

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, drop-down-menu

Would anyone be able to tell me the Greasemonkey code to make [this page](http://www.easportsworld.com/en_US/clubs/nhl) have "Any" as the default selected spoken language from the dropdown.

It defaults to English as selected for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following (very long) link will open the same page with "Any" as the default language option.  I don't know whether that meets your requirement?

> http://www.easportsworld.com/en_US/clubs/nhl/search?find[name]=&find[abbreviation]=&find[size]=&find[acceptJoinRequest]=&find[league]=&find[public]=&find[lang]=Any&find[platform]=xbox360&find[region]=&find[team_leagueId]=&find[teamId]=&do-search=submit